# Execute / test a class

Tags: java

I am not sure how to test my Java program (maybe not because of the test, potentially because of the coding before the test).

Here is the code and some embedded questions (all questions are numbered):

```
public class Trajet {
    int[][] plan;
    Posi deb; //This come from another class. 
    // 1/ Can I use it that way or should I build this class as a sister class of Posi?

    public Trajet() {
        plan = new int[10][10];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            plan[i][1] = 0;
        }
        plan[1][1] = plan[1][2] = plan[1][3] = plan[2][3] = plan[3][3] = plan[4][3] = plan[4][4] =
                plan[4][5] = plan[4][6] = plan[4][7] = plan[4][8] = 1;
        deb = new Posi(1, 1, 'S');
    }

    //Display the 10x10 table
    public void affichPlan(int[][] plan) {
        int n, m;
        for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
            for (m = 0; m < 10; m++) System.out.print(plan[n][m] + " ");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    //2. This is where I am stuck. I am supposed to test the code 
    // and display the table called 'plan'
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Trajet Trajet1 = new Trajet();
        Trajet1.affichPlan(Trajet1.plan);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many things wrong with your code. Let me just tell you all of them that I can find:

```
public class Trajet {
    private int[][] plan; 
    private Posi deb;

    // This isn't such a big deal, but if no other objects you know are going to use your fields, then its good practice to make them private.

    public Trajet() {
        plan = new int[10][10];
        // Instead of setting every 1st index to 0, the array will automatically be 0 when created. Also, the first index of an array is 0, not 1, in case you didn't know that. And setting the array at the first index to all 1's, you can use Arrays.fill();
        Arrays.fill(plan[0], 1);
        deb = new Posi(1, 1, 'S'); // Where do you use deb? And can we see the Posi class?
    }

    public void affichPlan(int[][] plan) {
        int n, m;
        for (n = 0; n < plan.length; n++) { // It's never a good idea to put the upper limit as a constant, even if you know it. Because if you're wrong, you're program would error out.
            for (m = 0; m < plan[i].length; m++) System.out.print(plan[n][m] + " ");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    // The reason its not working is because plan is non-static, that means it belongs to a specific object. For you to have plan, you need the object name. To fix this, I made plan static above.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Trajet trajet1 = new Trajet(); // Object names are always lowercase, and the second word and onwards are capital. Just how you make variable names in Java.
        Trajet1.affichPlan(trajet1.plan);
    }
}
```

Comment: And indeed, many many mistakes; but learning. That was one of my first piece of coding ever... I am in my first year of CS bachelor and I have a really bad Java teacher, so learning by myself